# Dynamic Loop in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I need some help to re-design this query into a Dynamic While Loop.
There is this `table A` which contains the number of iterations to run the loop as well as the values to pass to the  variables of the query.

```
acct_type_int|quarter_year_int|days_pass_end_period_int
          1      |  20172         |1529
          2      |  20171         |1619
          3      |  20181         |1169
```

The query below accepts the variables @var_acct_type_int, @var_quarter_year_int, and @var_days_pass_end_period_int from `table A`. It would run for 3 iterations since it has only 3 rows.

So for example, in this case the first iteration would get the values in row 1 of table A that is acct_type_int = 1 and quarter_year_int = 20172, days_pass_end_period_int=1529 and assign them to the variables @var_acct_type_int, @var_quarter_year_int, and @var_days_pass_end_period_int as seen in the query.

The resulting dataset created would be seen as below and **INSERTED** into `table_c`. Then the iterations would run 2 more times since there are 3 rows `in table A`

[image]

This is query so far:

```
INSERT INTO table_c
(
acct_type_int,
quarter_year_int,
update_day_pass_end_period_int
)         
SELECT 1 /*@var_acct_type_int*/ as acct_type_int, z.quarter_year_int, z.update_day_pass_end_period_int FROM(
    SELECT 
    a.quarter_year_int,
    case when 1529 /*@var_days_pass_end_period_int*/ + (90*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY quarter_year_int desc)) > 1799 then 1800 else 1529 /*@days_pass_end_period_int*/ + (90*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY quarter_year_int desc)) end AS update_day_pass_end_period_int FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    quarter_year_int
    from B where quarter_year_int < 20172 /*var_quarter_year_int*/ and acct_type_int = 1 /*@var_acct_type_int*/
    ) a
                      
    union all
                        
    SELECT 
    a.quarter_year_int, 
    case when 1529 /*@var_days_pass_end_period_int*/ - (90 *ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY quarter_year_int )) < 90 
                         then 179 else 1529 /*@var_days_pass_end_period_int*/ - (90 *ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY quarter_year_int )) 
    end  AS update_day_pass_end_period_int
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    quarter_year_int
    from B where  quarter_year_int > 20172 /*@var_quarter_year_int*/ and acct_type_int = 1 /*var_acct_type_int*/
    ) a
    ) z        
    --order by z.quarter_year_int
```

Comment: You don't appear to ask a question.  You should also isolate one aspect of your use case and create a ***minimal*** example focussed on that : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks. I'll Edit and start with a minimal use case.

Comment: It's entirely likely that you don't need a loop. Can you clarify / confirm in your example: one row in the source generates 22 rows in the target.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yes for each row in the source. It will generate 22 rows in target.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I think that using a `cursor` may help you out here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/cursor-in-sql-server/ Basically, you can run a `SELECT` statement to get results from a query, and then iterate through each row, using the data from the `SELECT` as variables. The link that I provided goes into more detail/examples. (Please note: There are not a TON of great cases in my experience that can't be done without, and cursors can be slow and messy).